# unable to get the attributes of an metadata of image using exif

Tags: javascript, exif

I want to get the metadata of image such as color space of an image at client side using java script.The code which I am using is here

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../exif.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 Upload a local file to read Exif data.
 <input id="file-input" type="file" />
 <script>
 document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function(e) {
                 var file =  e.target.files[0]
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
                    EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {
                            console.log("res.."+EXIF.pretty(this));
                    });
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting empty in the console.
What is the mistake I am doing over here?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked this code and some time I am also not getting metadata.

 
Your code is correct its dependent on images ,some images don't have/share the information that's why you are getting blank result try different images and you will get infromation.

For more read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/203592/what-is-exif-data-and-how-to-remove-it/).